# How can I tell which tab or plugin is crashing Firefox?

Tags: mac, firefox, crash, plugins

Every so often while I'm developing, Firefox will max out on CPU usage and I have no option but to  quit it (sometimes I have to force quit).

Is there a plugin/extension that is like the Chrome process list that tells me what tab/addon of Firefox is using up so much CPU? Memory actually isn't a problem as I have upgraded to 4GB but obviously there's nothing I can do about CPU.

This is only happening on at work on a Mac with the 64bit version of Firefox 4.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [BarTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/bartab/) to avoid loading all tabs at program launch. After starting FireFox, just let the tabs be loaded one by one.

To show the memory usage of all objects type `about:memory` into the address bar. Firefox also sends data about the crash to Mozilla. You can show this data with `about:crashes`, which is sometimes useful. It also can be useful to know which objects are cached: `about:cache`.

Comment: This is great however my problem occurs randomly, almost never at start up.

Comment: You should deavtivate all Plugins/Extensions. Activate them one by one. The most crashes are caused by Adobe Flash, so it's a good idea zu reinstall it. You can also use the [Add-on Compatibility Reporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/) to identify broken AddOns. Sorry, but there is no one-click solution for this problem. I hope Mozilla JetPack will solve such problems in future releases.